# How to run case when statement with spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to run a case when statement in a spark sql query.

Here is the data

```
object     green
______     _____
1           true
2           false
3           true
```

Here is the query

```
%sql

select 
    object,
    case when green is true then 'A'
        when green is false then 'B'
        else 'C' end as case_when_statement
from my_table
```

This query gives me this error: `mismatched input 'object' expecting <EOF>(line 3, pos 14)`

I've tried replacing `is true` with `= TRUE`, `= 'TRUE'` and `is TRUE`

Comment: what is the type of `green` column?

Comment: It is a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`==`** true.

```
spark.sql("""select 
    object,
    case when green == true then 'A'
        when green == false then 'B'
        else 'C' end as case_when_statement
from tmp""").show() 

//+------+-------------------+
//|object|case_when_statement|
//+------+-------------------+
//|     1|                  A|
//|     2|                  B|
//|     3|                  A|
//+------+-------------------+
```

**`In dataframe Api:`**

Use **`===`** true

```
df.withColumn("case_when_statement", when(col("green") === true,lit("A")).when(col("green")===false,lit("B")).otherwise(lit("c"))).show()
//+------+-----+-------------------+
//|object|green|case_when_statement|
//+------+-----+-------------------+
//|     1| true|                  A|
//|     2|false|                  B|
//|     3| true|                  A|
//+------+-----+-------------------+
```